# Running total is returning incorrect values in SSRS Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, msbi

I am trying to get the cumulative total but getting a different value in the running total.
I am getting below output

[Current OP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWjC4.png)

But I need O/p like this

[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0zGk.png)

Below are the formulas

**Received Invoices**: =Count(Fields!AWVNO.Value)

**Entered Invoices**: =split(Join(LookupSet(Fields!VDate.Value, Fields!EnteredDate.Value, Fields!VNO.Value, "DS_NAP"), ","),",").Length

**Daily Backlog** =Count(Fields!AWVNO.Value)- split(Join(LookupSet(Fields!VDate.Value, Fields!EnteredDate.Value, Fields!VNO.Value, "DS_NAP"), ","),",").Length

**Cumulative Backlog**  =RunningValue(Cint(Count(Fields!AWVNO.Value)- split(Join(LookupSet(Fields!VDate.Value, Fields!EnteredDate.Value, Fields!VNO.Value, "DS_NAP"), ","),",").Length),SUM, Nothing)

Note: I am receiving the data from 2 datasets which I am not able to combine due to limited access issue.

Comment: If it was me, I would do separate RunningValue() fields for each of the 3 expressions that you have (Received, Entered, Daily Backlog) - I suspect you'd find that the running value for two of them may be OK, and it's one of them that's throwing it out.  Obviously, the split/join/length thing that you're doing is slightly funky, and while we always want to hope that RunningValue() will just do what it seems like it should do, it can get a bit funked up from time-to-time with something a little out of the ordinary

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please suggest me something for Cumulative Backlog?

Comment: Bhushan, my suggestion was about how to do some troubleshooting to get to the bottom of your problem.  I suggest that checking separate RunningValue() results for your first two expressions (received invoices, entered invoices) should give you an indication of where an underlying problem may lie.  The split/join/lookupset expression may be confusing for SSRS to try and aggregate in the running value (I know it shouldn't confuse it, but sometimes SSRS does things we don't expect ....)

Comment: why not do this in your dataset - you can do a sum(your column) over (another column) and then simply disply it here.. assuming you are suing sqlserver for your datasource